# Trying to change the color of a J Button back and forth when it is clicked

Tags: java, swing, colors, boolean, jbutton

I am still a newbie when it comes to Java and I am attempting to change the color of a button every time it is clicked by using action listeners. But I have tried many different ways and have come to a road block... I have tried using a Boolean but I am still having problems with figuring this out.

```
Color change = Color.BLACK    
B.setForeground(change);
B.setContentAreaFilled(false);
B.setFocusPainted(false);
B.setBounds(100, 175, 75, 75);

R.add(B); // R is the JFrame the button is added to...

             B.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { //Action Listener when pressing should change the color from Black to Red
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            boolean right = false;
                            if (change == Color.BLACK) {
                                right = true;
                                B.setForeground(Color.red);
                            }
                        if (right == true) {
                            B.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                            right = false;
                        }

                    }

                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context...

```
B.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { //Action Listener when pressing should change the color from Black to Red
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        boolean right = false;
        if (change == Color.BLACK) {
            right = true;
            B.setForeground(Color.red);
        }
        if (right == true) {
            B.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            right = false;
        }
    }
});
```

`right` will always be `false`, as it's declared locally within the `actionPerformed` method.

Instead, make a instance field of the `ActionListener`, for example...

```
B.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { //Action Listener when pressing should change the color from Black to Red
    private boolean right = false;
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (change == Color.BLACK) {
            right = true;
            B.setForeground(Color.red);
        }
        if (right == true) {
            B.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            right = false;
        }

    }

});
```

Also, `change` never changes, so it's always `BLACK`, in which case I might be tempted to do something more like this...

```
B.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { //Action Listener when pressing should change the color from Black to Red
    private boolean right = false;
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (!right) {
            B.setForeground(Color.red);
        } else if (right) {
            B.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        }
        right = !right;
    }

});
```

Comment: Oh wow I should've seen that error, thank you for taking your time to help a beginner like myself, I appreciate people like you!  Thanks again.

Comment: @JoshuaSaikali There were some subtle things that caught me off guard to ;)